# Does TypeScript have untyped external modules?

Tags: typescript

In other words, can I import an external JavaScript module without (initially) caring about its typing?

In pseudo-TypeScript:

```
declare module "foo": any;
import foo = module("foo");
foo.bar;
foo.baz();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - although not specifically as a module:

```
declare var foo : any;
foo.bar;
foo.baz();
```

As you aren't defining the module in any way, this should be sufficient.

**Update**

If you want to get a `require` statement generated, you would need a stronger definition inside of a `foo.d.ts` file. I usually recommend the `require: any` hack that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Is that because you want it to generate the `require` statement?

Comment: Yes, trying to avoid `declare var require: any` and any similar hacks.

Comment: I like the optional typing aspect of TypeScript, which works for normal variables, so I don't understand why modules are treated separately. I guess a fix might be coming when http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/47 is implemented.